# Versioning with API Management and ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure-api-management, api-versioning

What's the difference between these two? I know how to do versioning in ASP.NET Core and recently I found out about the version in API Management and wonder about how to implement it or choose one over the other.

I search API Management docs and seems like it has the same implementation as ASP.NET Core, versioning scheme.

Comment: I feel that Azure API Management is for when you have a legacy but mission-critical web-service where it's too risky (or just too complicated) to try to implement versioning within it, but doing it from the outside is far less risky. (Considering that Azure's docs name-drop support for SOAP-based services I feel that's a dead giveaway that _Azure API Management_ is a place to run legacy web-services).

Answer (score 1):

You are totally correct that you can version an API with both Azure API Management (APIM) and directly inside your app with ASP.NET core.
Sometimes it can even make sense to version in both.
I would say that if you think you need versioning but are not sure where to start, use the versioning in ASP.NET Core.
If you later find that your use case was infact much more complicated you will probably want to use API Management aswell.

#### Version your API in ASP.NET Core app

Suitable when you are building a simple API app that you control and will be called by other services. Say that you are building this app for your workplace and another team will consume your API, but it will not be used *outside* your workplace organisation. Then versioning in the app code makes sense since it allows you to evolve your API without breaking it for your consumers and depending on another cloud service that will add complexity, management overhead and potentially cost (SKU dependent).
Your urls could look something like this as an example:

```
myapiapp.azurewebsites.net/v1/domain
myapiapp.azurewebsites.net/v2/domain
myapiapp.azurewebsites.net/v3/domain
```

#### Version your API with API Management and ASP.NET Core

API Management is a feature rich service and can do more than just version you API.
Now let's add on to the example above, say that you get an external organisation that want's to consume your API. Your internal API has 3 versions, but you only want the external consumers to be able to reach version 3 of your service. API management allows you to expose a subset of endpoints and versions of an API. Making it easy to restrict the external access. In this example we now practically have "internal versions" and "external versions" since both the service and APIM versions the API.
API Management is also a good choice if you are planning on exposing many of your API's to external customers, since it provides a unified point of entry.
Instead of exposing separate urls for each API to your customers as:

```
 myapiapp.azurewebsites.net/v3/domain
 otherteamapiapp.azurewebsites.net/v1/someotherdomain
```

It could look something like this exposed through APIM:

```
api.kan-company/v1/domain
api.kan-company/v1/someotherdomain
```

#### When to only version through API Management

I would say, like @Dai that you would wan't to version through API Management if you have an old legacy application that you can't change or the risk of change is too high.
Another scenario when to only version through API Management is if you have many API services that doesn't need changes that you would like to compose together or call through a unified endpoint.